# Get Error when Insert to Mongo collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collection that contains:

```
"DeviceId" : "",
"FirstName" : "", 
"LastName" : "", 
"AllowDomains" : "", 
"JobLocationName" : ""
```

and so on. I write this query that first check that `deviceId` in collection1 is the same of `deviceId` in collection2. If were same then do nothing otherwise must copy into temp Collection. 
but first:
It does not compare at all and these code copy all documents?
and second, middle of copy process I got error?

```
function compareCollection (dv, F2){

  var compare = F2.find().forEach(function(doc1){             

    if (doc1.DeviceId === dv ) {
      return false;
    } else {
      insertToColl(doc1.DeviceId)

    }
  });      
}


var result;
db.getCollection('FinalLocation').find({}, {DeviceId:  1}).forEach(function(u)
 {
  result = u.DeviceId;  
});

compareCollection(result , db.getCollection('FinalLocation_'));

function insertToColl(info){

 var post  = {
"DeviceId" : info,
"FirstName" : "", 
"LastName" : "", 
"AllowDomains" : "", 
"JobLocationName" : ""
};

db.getCollection('tempColl').save([post], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR ", err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("SUCCESS INSERTED in to users collection _is are ", result.length, result)
        }
    });
}
```

these error appear when mongo want's insert data into collection:

```
2017-09-26T15:41:47.467+0330 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: can't save a  number or string :

DBCollection.prototype.save@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:615:1

insertToColl@(shell):2:3

compareCollection/compare<@(shell):7:7

DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:501:1

compareCollection@(shell):2:17

@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: can you prove the value of device id?

Comment: @Arjit for testing, collection1 and collection2 are the same.that means, collection2 is copy of collection1. into collection1 there are 50 document with differ device id. in general this code should not copy any document into tempColl but these code has a mistake and does not work correctly.

Comment: @Arjit it seems `if (doc1.DeviceId === dv ) ` does not work Properly.

Comment: I could not find the error by just looking at the code an the test data. One thing I think you are doing wrong is that you ought to put your `compareCollection` inside the forEach i.e. just below `result = u.DeviceId`
And a way you can debug your code is by putting a `console.log()`  just before the `.save()` function

Comment: use `print("not equals. doc dev id: "+doc1.DeviceId+" dv: "+dv);` in your else statement of `compareCollection` function and provide the printed result here.